# Connection between variation of a function and its weighted integral

Tags: integration, proof-explanation, fourier-analysis, bounded-variation

The following is from "Multiplicative number theory I: Classical theory" by Hugh L. Montgomery, Robert C. Vaughan:

[image]

My question is that how Eq. D.10 is derived from the previous one? (The authors assume probably that $\text{var}$ is equal to or greater than the last two integrals but how that is derived?)

Comment: [Don't use images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, one comment was enough ...

Comment: One image was one too many.